# adding fields to the account register page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a website with mvc.
The website uses personal accounts to authenticate users.
On the register page, i have the automatically generated fields username, password and confirm password.
I want to add some extra fields to this register page.
How can I pass the information provided in these fieldsinto my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple steps involved to do this. The article at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-new-field is one of the better ones going through the detail.